# Resharper complains with a "Path Error" when using extensionless links

Tags: resharper

We have set up extensionless URLs on our site, but Resharper complains that paths are broken.  Is there some way to set up some type of wildcard mapping to add .cshtml to all of the links?

For example, Resharper complains about the following:

```
<li><a href="/demos/app-store">App Store</a></li>
```

But, if we add the extension, it stops complaining:

```
<li><a href="/demos/app-store.cshtml">App Store</a></li>
```

We have hundreds of links, so setting up a mapping per link is not a manageable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to suppress the error.
ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Severity -> HTML -> Potential Code Quality Issues -> Path error

I don't think that a wildcard mapping possible is.

But maybe the [Resharper Community Forum](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community) can help you.